# Convert between date/time and time-stamp without using standard library routines

Tags: c, datetime, converting, embedded, threadx

I am trying to implement two simple convertors: date/time to time-stamp and vice-versa, without any dependencies on time library routines (such as `localtime`, `mktime`, etc, mainly due to the fact that some of them are not thread-safe).

I have the following date/time structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char second; // 0-59
    unsigned char minute; // 0-59
    unsigned char hour;   // 0-23
    unsigned char day;    // 1-31
    unsigned char month;  // 1-12
    unsigned char year;   // 0-99 (representing 2000-2099)
}
date_time_t;
```

I would like to have a second opinion on the following conversion routines (given a legal input):

```
static unsigned short days[4][12] =
{
    {   0,  31,  60,  91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335},
    { 366, 397, 425, 456, 486, 517, 547, 578, 609, 639, 670, 700},
    { 731, 762, 790, 821, 851, 882, 912, 943, 974,1004,1035,1065},
    {1096,1127,1155,1186,1216,1247,1277,1308,1339,1369,1400,1430},
};


unsigned int date_time_to_epoch(date_time_t* date_time)
{
    unsigned int second = date_time->second;  // 0-59
    unsigned int minute = date_time->minute;  // 0-59
    unsigned int hour   = date_time->hour;    // 0-23
    unsigned int day    = date_time->day-1;   // 0-30
    unsigned int month  = date_time->month-1; // 0-11
    unsigned int year   = date_time->year;    // 0-99
    return (((year/4*(365*4+1)+days[year%4][month]+day)*24+hour)*60+minute)*60+second;
}


void epoch_to_date_time(date_time_t* date_time,unsigned int epoch)
{
    date_time->second = epoch%60; epoch /= 60;
    date_time->minute = epoch%60; epoch /= 60;
    date_time->hour   = epoch%24; epoch /= 24;

    unsigned int years = epoch/(365*4+1)*4; epoch %= 365*4+1;

    unsigned int year;
    for (year=3; year>0; year--)
    {
        if (epoch >= days[year][0])
            break;
    }

    unsigned int month;
    for (month=11; month>0; month--)
    {
        if (epoch >= days[year][month])
            break;
    }

    date_time->year  = years+year;
    date_time->month = month+1;
    date_time->day   = epoch-days[year][month]+1;
}
```

I have tested this on an extensive amount of legal input (between 01/01/2000 and 31/12/2099). Any constructive comments would be appreciated (performance improvement suggestions, readability, etc).

Comment: Your code will break for dates after 2100 (which is not a leap year), and you do not account for any timezones or daylight-savings.

Comment: Date-time math is *hard*. I suggest you rewrite an existing test suite for your library, e.g. from [the DateTime Perl module's](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) [test suite](https://metacpan.org/source/DROLSKY/DateTime-1.05/t). This should help you iron out most bugs. Note that using an `unsigned char` for a year opens up Y2K-style bugs, and that some minutes don't have 60 seconds. I also second rolfl's remark about the absence of time-zone awareness.

Comment: I explicitly stated in the question that legal input is in the range 2000 - 2099

Comment: Use `localtime_r()` etc. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2278919/1157100

Comment: I explicitly mentioned "with no dependency on std library routines". localtime_r uses a mutex (I'm guessing). I am unable to link this function to my system, which runs over STM32 (ARM based cortex) and ThreadX OS. So I need an OS agnostic solution.

Comment: Ironic/surprising that an OS named ThreadX wouldn't have a reentrant version of `localtime()`. Check the documentation? `localtime_r()` and friends are thread-safe not because of mutexes, but because they are designed not to use static variables, so there's no shared state between threads.

Comment: To my understanding (from other comments on a similar post of mine in stack-overflow), localtime_r simply encapsulates localtime with a mutex. Hence it is OS dependent and I cannot link it. Besides, even if ThreadX has a version of localtime_r, I would still like to avoid any use of OS resources in this case, as I don't see why such computation would require that in the first place.

Comment: Now, I've never done any real C programming, but you're passing in an instance of your date/time structure that is then mutated, right?  Which means that your code is no longer thread-safe either (if it can be shared, somebody'll do it); you'd be better off returning a new instance.  For that matter, I'm of the opinion that value types should generally be immutable when possible.  As a side note, you might want to check out Joda Time/JSR 310 - it's Java, but should be understandable; the base classes do this sort of thing.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thanks, but this code IS thread-safe. It consists of only two functions, and a read-only static object (called 'days'). No read/write static objects whatsoever (in opposed to 'localtime'). All computations are safely executed within the stack of the calling thread. I just wanted a second opinion on correctness, performance improvement, etc.

Comment: For this epoch unix timestamp "1442842561" i'm getting incorrect value for the date. Its shows year=45,month=9,**date=20**, hour=13, minutes=36, seconds=1.
But the date should be 21. Can you please resolve the bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Good that OP is using 4 simplifications: year 2000-2099, no DST, no leap second, no timezone.  So OP knows of code limitations concerning these.  Various elements of this function break without those givens.
2. Make `static unsigned short days` a `const`.
3. Use a `long` for your epoch as in:

   ```
   void epoch_to_date_time(date_time_t* date_time,unsigned long epoch)
   ```

   as `unsigned` is only guaranteed to range form 0 to at least 65535 which is insufficient here.
4. For various functions, consider adding `const`.  There are pros and cons to this, but may be beneficial in your case:

   ```
   // unsigned int date_time_to_epoch(date_time_t* date_time)
   unsigned int date_time_to_epoch(const date_time_t* date_time)
   ```
5. There exist equation based (non-loop) solutions to the year-day that do not need a table like your  `unsigned short days[4][12]`.  Code then looks more complicated, but is faster.  Please advise if interested.
6. Most of the magic numbers like 60, 24 are so well-known that constant or macro substitution seems superfluous.  But `(365*4+1)` may benefit with something like "DaysPer4Years".

Comment: Minor: `unsigned char hour;   // 0-59` should be `unsigned char hour;   // 0-23`.

Comment: Thank you. 2. Applied just before reading your answer. 5. Started with that approach, but code seemed much more complicated and much less readable; performance is not much different. 6. Thought about it when I wrote the code, but decided against it; macros are good when you want to keep the option of changing them in the future, which is not the case here.

Comment: @barak mano  Thanks for the clear feedback.  6. Macros and constants are useful for self-documentation too.  5. Equation is less space (embedded concern) .

Comment: thanks. Since I changed 'days' to constant, it now resides in the code-section (EPROM on my system) instead of in the data-section (RAM on my system). An equation will probably take the same amount of memory (96 bytes) in the code-section anyway.

Comment: @barak manos  I think I can well beat 96 bytes of code.  The ymd --> epoch has a code snippet of `if (m < March) { m += 12; y--; } d = ((m-March) * (7832/4) + (140/4)) >> (8-2);`.  Maybe later I'll post the entire thing for review and CC you.  A bit busy now.

Answer (score 2):

- This is too crammed for a single line:

  > ```
  > return (((year/4*(365*4+1)+days[year%4][month]+day)*24+hour)*60+minute)*60+second;
  > ```

  You should split this line somehow and put it in a helper function if it could be reused.
- Just keep these as two lines:

  > ```
  > unsigned int years = epoch/(365*4+1)*4; epoch %= 365*4+1;
  > ```

  You could also add a bit more whitespace for readability and make it `const`:

  ```
  const unsigned int years = epoch / (365 * 4 + 1) * 4;
  epoch %= 365 * 4 + 1;
  ```

  The first suggestion also applies to the three lines above this one.  It can be easy to mistake them as a single statement.  Plus, if you ever need to add additional statements to them, then they'll continue to get longer and hurt readability.